# ContactUI framework in iPad

Tags: objective-c

Getting error when I use contact framework in iPad application.

How to access contact list in iPad using contactui framework?

Here I have given my code:

```
CNContactPickerViewController *peoplePicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
peoplePicker.delegate = self;
NSArray *arrKeys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]; //display only phone numbers
peoplePicker.displayedPropertyKeys = arrKeys;
[self presentViewController:peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: getting this error  on third line of the code EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0*0) but in iPhone its works fine.